# How Do you Produce your own MEAM Potentials?

Tags: molecular-dynamics, ab-initio-calculations, interatomic-potentials

I have come across the [MEAM Parameter Calibration toolkit](https://icme.hpc.msstate.edu/mediawiki/index.php/MPC.html) (link leads to Wiki, video tutorials, and download link for the package) for fitting your own MEAM potentials [1].

Is this the best software out there for the job? Or is there another way of creating/ fitting your own MEAM potentials?

1. Barrett, C.D., Carino, R.L. The MEAM parameter calibration tool: an explicit methodology for hierarchical bridging between ab initio and atomistic scales. Integr Mater Manuf Innov 5, 177–191 (2016). [DOI](https://doi.org/10.1186/s40192-016-0051-6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't make any statement as to the quality of this program, but [MEAMfit](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cpc.2015.05.016) seems to be another package that can do what you are looking for.

The code isn't directly available online, but the article suggests emailing the authors for instructions on how to obtain the code.